# How can I keep a CREATE USER password from being logged in a Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, migration

I have a migration that creates a user on a database:

```
execute("CREATE USER reporter WITH PASSWORD '#{ENV.fetch('REPORTER_PASSWORD')}';")
```

That works great...except that Rails logs the raw command, which is unacceptable:

```
-- execute("CREATE USER reporter WITH PASSWORD 'super-secret';")
```

How can I run this migration without exposing the password in the logs?

Comment: This doesn't belong in a migration in the first place. Migrations are really just a way to programatically alter the **database schema** across environments in a repeatible way. They are not intended as the solution to all your database administration woes.

Comment: I would argue that the fact that this migration works says that the database user used by your Rails application has far to many priveledges and points to poor security practices.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the concern about excessive privileges, @max . I agree with you, and will address that in our app.

Answer (score 1):

Use [suppress_messages](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html#method-i-suppress_messages) to...well...suppress that message:

```
class CreateReporterUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def up
    suppress_messages do
      execute("CREATE USER reporter WITH PASSWORD '#{ENV.fetch('REPORTER_PASSWORD')}';")
    end
    puts '-- execute("CREATE USER reporter WITH PASSWORD [REDACTED];")'
    
    execute("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO reporter;") 
  end

  def down
    execute('DROP OWNED BY reporter') 
    execute('DROP USER IF EXISTS reporter;') 
  end
end
```